# Добраться до текста внутри класса

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть к примеру такой участок HTML кода:

```
<div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-wrapper">
  <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type">
    <button data-t="button:clear" data-type="login" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l 
    Button2_view_clear" autocomplete="off">
     ::before
      <span class="Button2-Text">Почта</span>
     ::after
    </button>
  </div>

</button></div><div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type">
  <button data-t="button:default" data-type="phone" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l 
  Button2_view_default" autocomplete="off">
   ::before
    <span class="Button2-Text">Телефон</span></button></div></div>
   ::after
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Можно ли, как то с помощью JS добраться до названий - "Почта" или "Телефон" по имени класса - "Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear" ?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.Button2-text').textContent`

Comment: @ΝNL993, да, но названия ".Button2-text" - минимум два в документе.
"

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.Button2-text').forEach(e => console.log(e.textContent))`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".Button2-Text")[1].innerText = "Phone"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот так:

```js
console.log('Текст напрямую от ребёнка -',
  document.querySelector('.Button2_size_l.Button2_view_clear .Button2-Text').textContent
)

console.log('Текст через родителя (С использованием trim) -',
   document.querySelector('.Button2_size_l.Button2_view_clear').textContent.trim()
)
```

```html
<div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-wrapper">
  <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type">
    <button data-t="button:clear" data-type="login" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear" autocomplete="off">
      <span class="Button2-Text">Почта</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type">
  <button data-t="button:default" data-type="phone" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_default" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="Button2-Text">Телефон</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы колдун, все работает :)

Comment: @Staxcelrom не за что! Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, изучить [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript) или попытайтесь сами найти ответ прежде чем задавать вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Запросто

`var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.Button2-Text')`

А дальше в зависимости от того, какой вам нужен `spans[0].innerText` или `spans[1].innerText`. Ну или в цикле перебирать

UPD: После пояснений автора корректировочка

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.Button2.Button2_size_l.Button2_view_clear');
var span = button.querySelector('span.Button2-Text');
var text = span.innerText;
```

Comment: Опечатался, поправил

Comment: Мне нужен именно в зависимости от класса - "Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear"

Comment: Что-то в духе: `var button = document.querySelector('.Button2.Button2_size_l.Button2_view_clear')`, а потом уже `var span = button.querySelector('span.Button2-Text')`